# Undefined Variable usando this

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou criando uma classe básica para operações no banco de dados, mas o apache me retorna dois erros na linha 12. Por a conexão se tratar de um atributo eu referencio com o `this`. Por que na primeira referência na hora de conectar ao db o erro não é dado?

Erros:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in C:\xampp\htdocs\MinhasFuncoes\php\model.php on line 12

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\MinhasFuncoes\php\model.php on line 12
```

View.php:

```
require_once 'model.php';
 $conn = new model("mysql","localhost", "teocratico", "utf-8","root","");
 $conn->consulta("descricao","desafios");
```

Model.php:

```
<?php
class model {
  private $conexao;
  public function __construct ($db, $host, $dbname, $charset, $usuario, $senha){
    try{
      $this->$conexao = new PDO ("$db:host=$host; dbname=$dbname; charset=$charset","$usuario","$senha");
    } catch (PDOException $erro){
        return $erro->getmessage();
    }
  }
  public function consulta ($campos, $tabela){
    $this->$conexao->prepare("SELECT :campos FROM :tabela;"); //Erro
    $this->$conexao->BindParam(':campos', $campos);
    $this->$conexao->BindParam(':tabela', $tabela);
    $this->$conexao->execute();
    $resultado = $this->$conexao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $resultado;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT campos FROM :tabela;` tire o **:campos** deixe como **campos** e **;** do final da `query` também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua lógica está certa, porém, não deve haver 2 `$`.

Altere em todos os lugares o `$this->$conexao` por `$this->conexao`